# Why is this triangle strip only painting a third of the screen?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to make a toy to "paint" fragment shaders on the whole screen. To that end I am attempting to "fill" the screen with a single triangle strip. I am using QT for this since I have a UI I want to use besides the openGL rendering.

I am basing the full screen triangle strip technique off: 
https://github.com/Gargaj/Bonzomatic/blob/master/src/platform_glfw/Renderer.cpp

```
static const char *fragmentShaderSource =
        "varying mediump vec4 color;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);\n"
        "}\n";


static float pFullscreenQuadVertices[] =
    {
      -1.0, -1.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
      -1.0,  1.0,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
       1.0, -1.0,  0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
       1.0,  1.0,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
    };

static const char *szVertexShader =
      "#version 410 core\n"
      "in vec3 in_pos;\n"
      "in vec2 in_texcoord;\n"
      "out vec2 out_texcoord;\n"
      "void main()\n"
      "{\n"
      "  gl_Position = vec4( in_pos.x, in_pos.y, in_pos.z, 1.0 );\n"
      "  out_texcoord = in_texcoord;\n"
      "}";


void DemoRender::initializeGL(){
         m_background = qRgb(255,255,255);
         initializeOpenGLFunctions();
         m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
         m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, szVertexShader);
         m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
         m_program->link();
         m_program->log();
         m_posAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("in_pos");

         m_vao1.create();
         m_vao1.bind();



}


void DemoRender::paintGL(){
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(this);

        painter.beginNativePainting();
        glClearColor(m_background.redF(), m_background.greenF(), m_background.blueF(),0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        //glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
        //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        m_program->bind();
        drawFullScreen();
        m_program->release();
           //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
           //glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

           painter.endNativePainting();

           painter.end();

           update();


}

void DemoRender::drawFullScreen(){

    m_vao1.bind();

    m_vbo1.create();
    m_vbo1.bind();
    m_vbo1.allocate(pFullscreenQuadVertices,sizeof(pFullscreenQuadVertices)*sizeof(float));
    m_vbo1.write(0,pFullscreenQuadVertices,sizeof(pFullscreenQuadVertices));


    m_program->enableAttributeArray(m_posAttr);

    //m_vbo1.release();
    //I suspect you are the culprit, but I don't know how to fix it. 
    m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_posAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);

    m_vbo1.release();

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


    m_program->disableAttributeArray(m_posAttr);

}
```

as a debug technique I am telling the fragment shader to make every pixel red. Now, my confusion is this: Why is only about a third of the screen turning red?

It appears the vertex shader isn't covering the entire screen space. What can I do to fix this?

My current theory is that the triangle strip isn't rendering right due to some detail of how the vertex array is set up, but because qt wont let me do this C-style I can't follow the original author's code one for one.

[image: Something is definitely wrong here]

Comment: setAttributeBuffer is part of QT... do you want me to include QT's library code in the example?

Comment: This is using QT's OpenGL bindings and their library functions. Like I said in the original post I can't do everything the C-Style way because obscures access to some of the C functions.

Comment: The third argument of setAttributeBuffer is offset... do you mean I should post 5*sizeof(float) as the stride? If it's taking a tuple of 3 why would the stride be 5?

Comment: It should be `m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_posAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 5*sizeof(float))`. Order in qt is `type, offset, size, stride`. The stride has to be set because every new vertex starts 5 floats after the last vertex. Your array contains position and two additional values, thus the stride has to be set manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertex attribute pointer, specifically the stride, is wrong. The data contains a 3-component position and two additional floats, but the default stride assumes tight packing. The correct code should be:

```
m_program->setAttributeBuffer(m_posAttr, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 5*sizeof(float))
```

Where `5 * sizeof(float)` is the by offset between the start of a vertex and the start of the next vertex.